# Styling input type search field like a text field

Tags: html, css, safari

I want my search field (in Safari) to look like an ordinary text field, (but with the addition of the x button to clear the search)

This is what I have so far:

http://jsfiddle.net/Pss4Z/1/

Basically, I'm just applying this to reset the style.

```
-webkit-appearance:textfield;
-moz-appearance:textfield;
```

All is well and good, except for one thing. In safari (haven't yet tested firefox), there is a blue border displayed around all input fields when you click in them. However, if you try that in this example, you'll notice that the display of that border is different between the text and search field;

With the text field, the blue border is directly over the gray border of the field, but with the search field, there's a bit of spacing, and you can see both the gray border and the blue border at the same time.

Is it possible to change it back to it's default behavior (like a text field)?

Thank you,
Wesley

Comment: Perhaps position an image over a normal textfield which resets the textfield once clicked on.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define border to get rid of that blue border effect.

http://jsfiddle.net/Pss4Z/5/

```
border: 1px solid gray;
```

This is for Firefox.

For Safari you need to add

```
outline: none;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Pss4Z/6/

Comment: Thanks, but as I said, I don't want to get rid of it, I want the border to behave like it does on a normal text field. Now it's a double border with the gray inner border.

Comment: You are not clear with your question. Can you say what EXACTLY do you want?

Comment: I suppose if you don't have the safari browser, you wouldn't notice it. There is a difference with the outline in safari, noticeable when you click in the first field, and then the second. The outline has a padding in the search field.

Comment: Yeah, I do have Safari. if you want to get rid of that padding why don't you simply remove:     -webkit-appearance:textfield;
    -moz-appearance:textfield; ??

Comment: it does have to look like a normal text field.